# How to change output folder name from installShield 2010 project?

Tags: installation, installshield

The output directory from install shield 2010 project contains an file with name 0x0409.ini, an file with name Setup.ini, an file with name setup.exe, an file with name my application name.msi and one folder with name "programm files". Anybody know how to change this folder name ?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the `[ProgramFilesFolder]` node in the Files and Folders view of the Installation Designer tab, and select Properties, the Properties dialog will appear. In that dialog, the `Source Location` field should allow you to change the name of folders in your uncompressed media. You can give it a new name, or possibly even `.` to say don't use a folder name for this level, instead showing folders from the level beneath it.